# "Navigator.pointerEnabled. It will be removed in near future." Leaflet warning

Tags: leaflet

I build a Leaflet GIS. In error console I have this:

`"Navigator.pointerEnabled is a non-standard API added for experiments only. It will be removed in near future."`

I can't understand it what does this mean?
How to solve this problem. Before a while developer console says no error but now there is a warning says that Navigator.pointerEnabled it will be removed in near future?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Comment: Are you using a current version of leaflet? Does your code use Navigator.pointerEnabled , or is this something used by leaflet?

Comment: I changed to older version of leaflet and same problem.I am not usingNavigator.pointerEnabled, it is inside leaflet I guess.

Comment: My code is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/1djKzGYJTWChGMDBrsVD?p=preview
go to my GIS with tools of debuging in your browser developper tools in the console of errors it shows that warning ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference to `navigator.pointerEnabled` was removed from the Leaflet code in March 2016, as you can check at https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/4287.

Upgrade your code to use Leaflet 1.0.0-rc1 (or newer), and that warning will go away.

Comment: How about other plugins extension they must be latest to support Leaflet 1.0.0-rc1 .because I get errors with  Leaflet 1.0.0 and old extension .How to do to use the same code and never change it because I have to give it to client .

Comment: Plugin compatibility with Leaflet 1.0.0 is a different problem.

Comment: I want to stay in v0.7.7 my GIS has lot of plugins running on it forget about that warning ;my GIS stay working for ever or will be stoped soon the navigator.pointerEnabled will be removed